# exchange of measurement errors in 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have very large evaluation data of strain readings which I import as 2d arrays into python. Short Example:

```py
X = np.array([[210, 211, 209, 10000, 215, -5000],
              [220, 221, 219, 10000, 225, -10000],
               1400, 225, 230, 10000, 235, -98]])
```

Some measured values can be interpreted directly as measurement errors (e.g.:`10000,-5000`). I define them with an interval (e.g.: `<-10, >1000`). Then the values should be removed from the array and replaced by suitable values. The measurement errors should either be interpolated or replaced by other methods.

I already had a few attempts with the Panda's function `asfreq()` and imputation class from scikit-learn. With `asfreq()` I had the problem that it only fills `NaN` values. With `imputer()` there are only the four strategies (mean, median, most frequent and constant).

Comment: What would you like values to be filled with? Your question is a little broad.

Comment: interpolated values

Comment: Sure, but what method of interpolation do you want?

Comment: that depends on the results. I have experimented with cubic splines or the Akima method.

Comment: Could you provide your some more context? What if your 2D array? Are the columns strain readings at different positions and the rows readings at different times?

Comment: Yes, the columns display the strain readings at different positions. The distance between the measuring points (columns) is identical. The rows represent the time of the measurement.